# Sharing exception handling code for multiple exception types

Tags: swift, exception, try-catch

PHP 7.1 introduces a way to reuse exception handling code for multiple exception types.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/multiple-catch

```
<?php

try {
   // Some code...
} catch (ExceptionType1 | ExceptionType2 $e) {
   // Code to handle the exception
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   // ...
}
```

Does Swift 3 offer a similar way, e.g. by using a where clause in the catch expression?

Comment: Here you can find all information that you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: And I wonder where I found the information about where clauses in catch expressions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
catch let error where error is ErrorType1 || error is ErrorType2
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the ErrorTypes have associated values.

Comment: @Etan, and how did you imagined getting associated value using `one of this types in the list` type declaration? In this case you **have to** use separate catch for type.

Comment: The enum case has associated values, but during the catch I'd like to discard them.

Assuming it's `Error.type1(value: Int)` and `Error.type2(value: Int)`, you can just write `catch Error.type1` and `catch Error.type2` without any issues. However, when you try the proposed `||` solution, it won't work anymore.

Comment: @Etan, Maybe it doesn't work 'cos `is` operator works **with types, not enum values**. If you need to switch between values you should use something like `catch let error as <your error enum type> { switch error { case … } }`.

Comment: Yep, we are at the same stage now :-) Looks like there is no clean way to catch multiple errors yet when associated values are involved.